# The meta-data does not have the right value Google Maps v2 on Android API 10

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

I am trying to check my Google play store services availability in my application using **servicesOK** method but it crashes with an unexpected error that meta data tag doesn't contain right values.

**Code:**

```
 **protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(servicesOK()){

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
}
public boolean servicesOK(){
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }
    else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    return false;
}**
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webmonopolists.project_linx"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="17"
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.Main_Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.SourceDestinationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_source_destination" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.Routemap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_routemap" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.RouteSummary"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_route_summary" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.webmonopolists.project_linx.SavedRoutes"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_saved_routes" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAmiJ6vLbgWGEtge0g_9Gwdn7xIymjl92c"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Log Data:**

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webmonopolists.project_linx/com.webmonopolists.project_linx.HomeScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1734)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1753)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:999)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzJ(Unknown Source)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.webmonopolists.project_linx.HomeScreen.servicesOK(HomeScreen.java:48)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.webmonopolists.project_linx.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:21)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1698)

01-02 04:43:06.781: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your existing `<meta-data>` element, add another one:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

You will find this on any Maps V2 sample that is less than a year old, including all of them in [this directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2).